# Node js Veracode CWE 201 issue: Insertion of sensitive information into sent data

Tags: veracode

I have Node js api to get the details from dynamo db.

Below is the code.

*1.

```js
var params = {

  TableName: ‘TABLE’,

  Key: {

    ‘id’: 1,
    Module: 'Module1'

  },
  projectionExpression:'Expression1'

};
```

2. 

```js
let ddbDocClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

3. 

```js
var response = await this.ddbDocClient.get(params).promise();
```

when I perform the veracode scan  line number 3 is giving CWE 201 error saying insertion of sensitive information into sent data.
I cloudn't find any answer in vercacode dcumentation also.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

I tried to implement HtmlEncode similar to .net but it seems like node js doesn't have that option.